# Coordinates relation in dual bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional inner product space and $\mathcal B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ and $\mathcal C=(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ are bases of $V$ such that $\langle b_i,c_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$. Is there any simple relation between the coordinates $[v]_{\mathcal B}$ and $[v]_{\mathcal C}$ of an arbitrary vector $v$ in these bases?

Comment: They would be related by an appropriate orthogonal matrix. There isn't much you can say beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some calculations I've found the answer, sharing it here. Let's find the change of basis matrix $M_{\mathcal B,\mathcal C}$ from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal C$ so that $[v]_{\mathcal C}=M_{\mathcal B,\mathcal C}[v]_{\mathcal B}$. To do so we have to express vectors of $\mathcal B$ in $\mathcal C$: $M_{\mathcal B,\mathcal C}=\left[\,[b_1]_{\mathcal C},\ldots[b_n]_{\mathcal C}\,\right]$. But it is natural to consider ${\mathcal B}$ as a given basis and ${\mathcal C}$ as the corresponding dual, so it is desirable to get an answer in terms of ${\mathcal B}$. So let's express $\mathcal C$ in $\mathcal B$, then $M_{\mathcal B,\mathcal C}=M_{\mathcal C,\mathcal B}^{-1}$:
$$
c_l=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n[c_l]_{\mathcal B}^jb_j.
$$
Inner multiply by $b_k$:
$$
\langle b_k,c_l\rangle=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n[c_l]_{\mathcal B}^j\langle b_k,b_j\rangle=\delta_{kl},
$$
and so
$$
G(\mathcal B)\,M_{\mathcal C,\mathcal B}=I,\\
M_{\mathcal C,\mathcal B}=G(\mathcal B)^{-1},\\
M_{\mathcal B,\mathcal C}=G(\mathcal B),\\
[v]_{\mathcal C}=G(\mathcal B)\,[v]_{\mathcal B}
$$
where $G(\mathcal B)$ is the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of $\mathcal B$, i.e. $G(\mathcal B)_{ij}=\langle b_i,b_j\rangle$.